# How to get path of class library when calling from a web application? 

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a class library that is reading some XSLT files. I was using resources but they were precompiled within the dll and we want to be able to alter those files on the fly, so I've been asked to read them from the filesystem.

I started using a relative path and the unit tests run fine, but the integration ones are failing because in this case they are running the web applications and turn out with a wrong path.

The code is very simple, it's just loading the xslt:

```
string xslFilePath = @"xslts\transformation1.xsl";
XslCompiledTransform transformation = new XslCompiledTransform();
transformation.Load(xslFilePath, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());
```

The error in the integration tests is:

> DirectoryNotFoundException ExceptionMessage - Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\xslts\transformation1.xsl'.

The nearest solution I've found so far is:

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Class1)).CodeBase;
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
string fullPath = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
string theDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
string relativePath = @"\xslts\transformation1.xsl";
string path = theDirectory + relativePath;
```

But it's retrieving a wrong path, this time it's the path of the web application that's using that dll. I'm still trying find a solution, it must be a way to get the dll path.

Comment: What is actual location of file to be read?

Comment: Let's say that the location is: c:\dll\xslts\file.xsl and that dll is used by a web application that is in c:\webapplication. I started to think that's not possible and I need to move those xslts to the web application directory, but it wouldn't make much sense to me, because they would be used only by that dll.

Comment: dll added as reference will be copied to \bin. So use absolute path. Or embed file as resource

Comment: I was embedding the file as resource but the file must be able to change on the fly, and as resource it's precompiled into the dll. I need some way to read it from the filesystem.

Comment: do you need to save modified file back?

Comment: It's a transformation that generates some kind of response, and if for some reason a change is needed in that response, we should be able to change that transformation. At the moment it's using resources, and we needed to make a change and we had to recompile that dll instead of just changing the transformation.

Comment: i can recommend you to place files in well-known location, e.g. c:\xslts, and access it via absolute path. or place into ~/App_Data

Comment: App_Data folder would be an option, but it means that I've got to move the xslts to the web application, even though they're being used only by that particular class library.

Comment: The App_Data approach makes unit test failed, they are expecting those files to be within the class library directory (as it should be) but they're in the web application. On top of that, if afterwards I need to use the same dll in another project, I'd need to copy those xslts there, causing duplication.

Comment: You can edit unit test to support absolute path, then `Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/transformation1.xsl")` will give you e.g. `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\App_Data\transformation1.xsl`. So use `tranform.Load(XmlReader.Create(new StreamReader(path)))` or just `tranform.Load(path)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the work you are doing is under the ASP .NET process you can use:

```
Server.MapPath("\xslts\transformation1.xsl")
```

This will give you the physical path to the file, i.e.

> C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\xslts\transformation1.xsl

More information can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=VS.90).aspx

and here:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210417074237/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/121799-1.shtml

**EDIT**

Alternative put a "PathToXsl" appsetting in your web.config - this could prove to be useful in the future.

Comment: The problem is that the xslts are not in the web application directory, they are in the dll directory. And It doesn't make sense to move those files over to the web application directory because they are used only by the dll.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think you can also use relative paths on MapPath. Lets say that you xslts are in c:\xslts\ and you web app in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\myapp, MapPath("..\..\..\xslts") may work - will need testing though.  Alternatively consider the solution in the edit to my original response.

Comment: MapPath doesn't work. It throws an exception: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.